# How to find interdependencies between pods in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Two Pods run in a Kubernetes cluster. One is a simple Wordpress application and the other a Mysql database. The Wordpress Pod communicates with the Mysql database.

The aim is to find dependencies between pods. Is there any kubectl command or any tool like prometheus that is able to find interdependence between Pods?

Comment: How did you create these pods?

Comment: By using deployment yaml files

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to solutions implementing a service mesh.

For example ISTIO, Consul, Ambasador + Envoy...

Answer (score 2):

Weave Scope is an observability tool that provides a dashboard that shows all network connections between pods.

https://github.com/weaveworks/scope

Answer (score 1):

One way to find interdependencies is to check the services page when `kubectl proxy` has been issued and one navigates to http://localhost:8001. For example, if one deploys wordpress pods then a MySql pod and a wordpress pod will be created. As wordpress has to use a database like MySql one could see that the wordpress connects to the Mysql pod in the services page.

The help command of kubectl was consulted whether there is a subcommand that shows interdependencies, but that does not seem to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a trace-based monitoring tool, eg something OpenTracing compatible. These will show requests as they flow through the entire system, allowing you to visualize dependencies.